# Positioning spinner within UIAlertController

Tags: swift

I have a `UIAlertController` with a title and spinner. I need the spinner to be displayed just below the title, but I'm struggling to position it. In fact, I'm setting `spinner.center` to the center of the screen, but it's actually appearing in the lower right hand corner.

```
var alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Fetching New Music", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)

spinner.color = UIColor.yellowColor()

spinner.startAnimating()

alert.view.addSubview(spinner)

var height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.15)

alert.view.addConstraint(height)

// Here is where I need help!          
spinner.center = CGPointMake((self.view.frame.width / 2) - (spinner.frame.width / 2), (self.view.frame.height / 2) - (spinner.frame.height / 2))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines, taken together, make no sense:

```
alert.view.addSubview(spinner)
spinner.center = CGPointMake((self.view.frame.width / 2) - (spinner.frame.width / 2), (self.view.frame.height / 2) - (spinner.frame.height / 2))
```

It would appear that you have not grasped the fundamental difference between `frame` and `bounds`. If you are going to add the spinner as a subview of the alert view (as in the first line), then the position of the spinner's `center` (as in the second line) is defined in relation to *the alert view's bounds*, not some other object's *frame*.

Comment: On the whole, however, I would advise that you not do this at all. You have no "right" to add any subviews to an alert view.

Comment: Hmm. I'd really like to do this. Why exactly would you recommend not doing this?

Comment: For the reason that I gave. This view is not yours to mess with. What you're trying to do is unsupported.